# Pandas mapping all, and a portion, of column value in another column

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to search for values and *portions* of values from one column to another and return a third value.

Essentially, I have two dataframes:  df and df2.  The first has a part number in 'col1'.  The second has the part number, *or portion of it*, in 'col1' and the value I want to put in df['col2'] in 'col2'.

```
import pandas as pd


df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-1-3',
    '2-1-1', '2-1-2', '2-1-3']})

df2 = pd.DataFrame({'col1': ['1-1-1', '1-1-2', '1-1-3', '2-1'],
    'col2': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})
```

Of course this:

```
df['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])
```

Only covers everything that matches, not the portions:

```
df['col1'].isin(df2['col1'])
Out[27]: 
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: col1, dtype: bool
```

I tried:

```
df[df['col1'].str.contains(df2['col1'])]
```

but get:

```
TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed
```

I also tried use a dictionary made from df2; using the same approaches as above and also mapping it--with no luck

The results for df I need would look like this:

```
 col1     col2
'1-1-1'    'A'
'1-1-2'    'B'
'1-1-3'    'C'
'2-1-1'    'D'  
'2-1-2'    'D'  
'2-1-3'    'D'
```

I can't figure out how to get the 'D' value into 'col2' because df2['col1'] contains '2-1'--only a portion of the part number.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can do `str.findall`

```
s=df.col1.str.findall('|'.join(df2.col1.tolist())).str[0].map(df2.set_index('col1').col2)

df['New']=s

df
    col1 New
0  1-1-1   A
1  1-1-2   B
2  1-1-3   C
3  2-1-1   D
4  2-1-2   D
5  2-1-3   D
```

Comment: This guy's a hero.

Comment: Thank you!  I can't tell you how much time this is going to save!

Comment: nasty one liner

Answer (score 1):

If your `df` and `df2` the specific format as in the sample, another way is using a dict `map` with `fillna` by mapping from  `rsplit`

```
d = dict(df2[['col1', 'col2']].values)
df['col2'] = df.col1.map(d).fillna(df.col1.str.rsplit('-',1).str[0].map(d))

Out[1223]:
    col1 col2
0  1-1-1    A
1  1-1-2    B
2  1-1-3    C
3  2-1-1    D
4  2-1-2    D
5  2-1-3    D
```

---

Otherwise, besides using `findall` as in Wen's solution, you may also use `extract` using with dict `d` from above

```
df.col1.str.extract('('+'|'.join(df2.col1)+')')[0].map(d)
```